# How to use mongoose findOne

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose

I have the below schema (apologies that it is in coffeescript)

```
Schema = mongoose.Schema

AuthS = new Schema
    auth:   {type: String, unique: true}
    nick:   String
    time:   Date
Auth = mongoose.model 'Auth', AuthS
```

I simply want to recover one record which is definitely in my database:

```
Auth.findOne({nick: 'noname'}, function(obj) { console.log(obj); });
```

Unfortunately this always logs `null`. `db.auths.findOne({nick: 'noname'})` in mongo shell always returns a value. What is going on?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Found the problem, need to use `function(err,obj)` instead:

```
Auth.findOne({nick: 'noname'}, function(err,obj) { console.log(obj); });
```

Comment: When I use `findOne` like this I get my data successfully but `obj` is not a `Document` object. When I try `obj.nick` and `obj[nick]` I get undefined. When I try `obj.get('nick')` I get object does not have method get. I tried many JSON conversions and creating a `doc = new Document(obj)`. I also tried `doc.toObject(obj)` and `doc.set(obj)`;

Comment: @JonathanCzitkovics I think that if you do obj.toObject() that would give you what you were looking for.

Comment: When the operation executes succesfully (err is null), but there is no match, the document will be null too.

Comment: But how are you getting the object inside of findOne?  I am assuming this info would be in a route.  req.body?

Comment: @JonathanCzitkovics . Thank you. But please let me know the reason. Only for one project i am using like this for others i can just use . symbol

Answer (score 14):

Mongoose basically wraps mongodb's api to give you a pseudo relational db api so queries are not going to be exactly like mongodb queries.  Mongoose **findOne** query returns a query object, **not a document**.  You can either use a callback as the solution suggests or as of v4+ **findOne** returns a thenable so you can use .then or await/async to retrieve the document.

```
// thenables
Auth.findOne({nick: 'noname'}).then(err, result) {console.log(result)};
Auth.findOne({nick: 'noname'}).then(function (doc) {console.log(doc)});

// To use a full fledge promise you will need to use .exec()
var auth = Auth.findOne({nick: 'noname'}).exec();
auth.then(function (doc) {console.log(doc)});

// async/await
async function async auth() {
  const doc = await Auth.findOne({nick: 'noname'}).exec();
  return doc;
}
auth();
```

See the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) if you would like to use a third party promise library.

Answer (score 10):

In my case same error is there , I am using Asyanc / Await functions , for this   needs to add AWAIT for findOne

```
Ex:const foundUser = User.findOne ({ "email" : req.body.email });
```

above , foundUser always contains Object value in both cases either user found or not because it's returning values before finishing findOne .

```
const foundUser = await User.findOne ({ "email" : req.body.email });
```

above , foundUser returns null if user is not there in collection with provided condition . If user found returns user document.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using `console.log` with the built-in "arguments" object:

```
console.log(arguments); // would have shown you [0] null, [1] yourResult
```

This will always output all of your arguments, no matter how many arguments you have.

Answer (score 0):

Use obj[0].nick and you will get desired result,

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give an updated answer for 2023. Using the listed methods I was unable to get it to work and got the error:

```
MongooseError: Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback
```

The way I got it to work is using promises.

```
Auth.findOne({nick: 'noname'}).then(user=>{

    if(user){
        //do something
    }

}).catch(err=>{handle err})
```