# How to perform findOne query in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have mongoose schema named administrator

```
var administratorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

username : String,            
password : String,
    active : Boolean,
    level : String
});
```

When i try this query,i can get the result

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://'+dbServer+'/'+dbName, function(connectionError) {
        var administratorModel = mongoose.model('administrators',administratorSchema);
        administratorModel.findOne({_id,111155dffxv}function(err, resad){
            console.log('into mongoose findone');
        });
});
====> Console output : 'into mongoose findone'
```

The problem is : when i try to change the criteria from _id to "username", mongoose dosen't work and findOne dosen't execute:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://'+dbServer+'/'+dbName, function(connectionError) {
        var administratorModel = mongoose.model('administrators',administratorSchema);
        administratorModel.findOne({'username','mohamed'}function(err, resad){
            console.log('into mongoose findone');
        });
});
====> Console output : ''
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use mongoose findOne](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033331/how-to-use-mongoose-findone)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your query object isn't valid (use a colon instead of a comma) and you're missing a comma between the `findOne` parameters.  Your call should look like this instead:

```
administratorModel.findOne({'username': 'mohamed'}, function(err, resad){
     console.log('into mongoose findone');
});
```

You should also be checking the `err` parameter of your callbacks to see if things are working.

Not sure why it was reaching the callback with your `_id` criteria version as that one has the same issues.

Comment: Thank your for replying to my question,

Comment: you have to do always a callback when calling findone ?