# Mongoose findOne.stream() returning more than one document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to query for one document, and I'd like to pipe it to a stream. My database has multiple account documents.  If I simply:

```
db.Accounts.findOne({}).exec(function(err, data){
   ...
});
```

it correctly returns a single document.  However,

```
var mongooseStream = db.Accounts.findOne({}).stream({ 
  transform: JSON.stringify
}),
  writeStream = require('fs').createWriteStream('accounts');

mongooseStream.pipe(writeStream);
```

this newly created writeStream above has every account listed inside of it.

Lastly, if I `.find({}).limit(1).stream()`, it will return only one document in the stream.

Any ideas on why streaming `findOne({})` isn't working as I expect it to?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have not put any condition on the `findOne()` and moreover you are streaming it. Therefore it is continuously doing `findOne()` and then supplying it to the stream. `findOne()` is used as follows :

```
SchemaModel.findOne({
     //conditions
},function(){
     //this is callback
});
```

From what i understand you are trying to do is, you are trying to stream only one document of the collection. For that i say, `findOne` is not what you need, because `findOne` is used to extract exactly one document directly in the form of Javascript object from the database when you define a set of condtions.

Read :

[Mongoose Queries](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

[db.Collection.findOne()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)

[How to use mongoose findOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033331/how-to-use-mongoose-findone)

Comment: Even with empty conditions in your code above, it will return one document using the callback method.  I understand it's not the best method of writing one document to a stream, but I still am confused as to why it's returning more than one document/running findOne continuously (even when conditions are specified)

Comment: True it returns one document.. but mind that you are streaming the data here.