# Mongoose findOne produces no output or delivers whole database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created a function to create a profile document, based on a schema, into mongoDB, which works so far:

```
const createUpdateProfile = (req, res) => {
    let uuid = req.user.identities[0].id;
    let provider = req.user.identities[0].provider;
    let email = req.user.email;
    let firstName = req.user.name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
    let lastName = req.user.name.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' ');
    let pictureUrl = req.user.picture;
    let profileToSafe = new Profile({
        uuid: uuid,
        provider: provider,
        email: email,
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName
    });
    const profile = Profile.findOne({ uuid });
    if (profile !== null) {
        profileToSafe.save();
    }
    res.status(200).send('successful operation');
}
```

I checked the DB and the document has been stored there.

But I cannot read it.

```
const getProfile = (req, res) => {
    let uuid = req.user.identities[0].id;
    Profile.findOne({ uuid: uuid }), function (obj) { console.log(obj) }, function (err) { console.log(err) };
    res.status(200).send('successful operation');
}
```

There is simply no console log output. Not even a null or an error.

I did as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033331/how-to-use-mongoose-findone) also I tried to console log findOne function but it returns kind of the whole database, including the authentication data.

Answer (score 0):

You have close the parameter list to the `findOne` method too early in your second snippet.

```
Profile.findOne({ uuid: uuid }), function (obj) { console.log(obj) }, function (err) { console.log(err) };
```

should be

```
Profile.findOne({ uuid: uuid }, function (obj) { console.log(obj) }, function (err) { console.log(err) });
```