# TypeError: login.findOne(...).toArray is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this function, whcih bascially gets the usernmae and password of the users input from the front-end form, and then checks it in mongodb:

```
 app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {

    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    //connecting to the mongo client
  client.connect().then (() => {
    
    //defining database name and collection
    const database = client.db("myFirstDatabase");
    const login = database.collection("login");
    
    //connecting to the mongo client
    MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;


      //finding all documents inside array
        login.findOne({"username": username}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;

            result.forEach(results => 
                bcrypt.compare(password, results.password, function(err, result) {
                    if (result === true) {
                        req.session.loggedin = true
                        next()
                    } else {
                        res.redirect('/login')
                    }
                })
            );

            db.close();
        });
    });
})
})
```

however, it is giving me this error:

```
TypeError: login.findOne(...).toArray is not a function
```

i've never encountered this error before. how do i fix this?

Comment: findOne returns an object, not a query or iterable.

Comment: @Joe so how would i try to see if the username matches the one the user entered?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7033621/2282634

Comment: Noting, in the older driver 2.x era of mongo native driver, the above code used to work.  In the 4.x driver this will fail exactly as described.  Others have described the answer correctly, but you were not wrong that somewhere on the internet or maybe in the old code this was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
login.findOne({"username": username}, function(err,user) 
{ console.log(user); });
```

Answer (score 0):

`FindOne` means, it gives single object so, you can't get array.
If you use find then u you can use `find().toArray()`.